# Android Fragment : bug fix explanation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm starting using Fragments, and I've done like the API guide but ... of course it'd be too easy ;)
When I launch the app, it crashes. After some research I've found this post [Android fragment is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662720/android-fragment-is-not-working)
and the response of Stephen Wylie seems to correct the things for Ali, but .. I don't get it !
Where should I put the FrameLayout ?  The "where_i_want_my_fragment" id... it's whatever I want, right ?
and finally where should I put the Java code ? in my activity (which is displaying 2 fragments by the way) .

Thanks !

Nico

EDIT : Let's just say what I want for design you would understand better I think.
I want a list fragment on left side which display a list of strings, and to the right side I want a fragment displaying info regarding the selected string in the list. And I wanna be able to swip with fingers movements the right side of my app (I dont know if it s better to swipe fragment or whatever.. It's the same layout but filled with differents datas)

Ok I just post my code because I really don't see why it doesn't do anything.
This is my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_frag"
    android:name="main.courante.c.DateListFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fiche_frag"
    android:name="main.courante.c.fiche_frag"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my main activity :
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DateListFragment fragment = new DateListFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list_frag, fragment).commit();
    fiche_freg frag2 = new fiche_frag();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fiche_frag,frag2).commit();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here is DateListFragment (no onCreateView because it 's automatically generated)

```
public class DateListFragment extends ListFragment {
private int mposition = 1;
private String[] mListItem = new String[] {
        "Lundi 9 Juilllet",
        "Mardi 10 Juillet",
        "Mercredi maintenant"
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                     (this.getActivity(),R.layout.frag_list_view ,mListItem));
    this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}
```

and here is fiche_frag :
    public class fiche_frag extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.checks_matin,container,false);
}
```

R.layout.checks_matin works fine alone.

I thank you already and again for your help. I'm a beginner in android environnement and I find it difficult to englobe every notions for the UI at once... !!

Comment: If you are going to use the activity to put the fragments in you should remove the `android:name` tags from the xml.

Comment: I would also use `onActivityCreated` in the fragments instead of `onCreate`.

Comment: A link to the [Fragment docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#UI) which might be helpful.

Comment: Wow great !!! it shows something !!! =) I push my luck a little bit further and I ask you a little something else : How can I change the layout inside my right fragment ? Because here I use fragment inside framelayout, so my fragment have no id's or tag because it's not in xml so how can I do to retrieve my fragment by tag or id (only thoses two) ? for example when I click on a button, I'd like it to change the layout of my right fragment. But maybe my design is bad.

Comment: but a GREAT thanks anyway. been spending a lot more time than I thought on this ..

Comment: You can add an `android:tag` in your XML, or reference it by the container id ( its explained in that link I gave you somewhere :p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand the basics.  The `FrameLayout` goes wherever you want your fragment(s) to go.  I've done it where my whole screen was one single `FrameLayout` before and I swapped up to five different fragments in and out of it.

If you have two Fragments that you want to display simultaneously, you could make your main layout with two `FrameLayout`s.  However, this means you are locked into having both there all the time (or an empty space if you remove one.

If you want two fragments that don't have to be on the screen at the same time you use a single `FrameLayout` and write code to swap the fragments as required.

Code to instantiate fragments should always be in the controlling activity (if they are dynamic).

Without code and a more specific problem, the above is the best answer I can give you.

**EDIT**

An example main layout to put two fragments side by side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frames"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/hline1"
        android:layout_below="@id/horizontalline"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftpane"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".4" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/rightpane"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
...
```

To add your fragment to one of the framelayouts:

```
FragmentClass fragment = new FragmentClass();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.leftpane, fragment).commit();
```

If you want to swap fragments in one of the framelayouts (say the left pane), you can do it like this:

```
FragmentClass fragment = new FragmentClass();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.leftpane, fragment).commit();
```

I suggested instantiating from the XML because it sounded like you were going to have two fragments and not make any changes.  If you are going to swap them in and out, then it would be appropriate to add a tag to each one so you can find them again if you want to display them again.

Comment: It's exactly that. So If i want the two fragments always there, I simply create a layout (linearlayout in a xml file for example) composed of two FrameLayout's.  I create one main activity with this layout, and in the onCreate / resume function of the main activity I put the java code. Did I understood it right ? well i'll test it though. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: You've got it.  :)  You could also put `android:name="your.package.name.fragmentclassname` in the framelayouts (with the appropriate different fragment class names) and that will cause the fragments to be instantiated automatically when the layout is inflated, so you wouldn't need to put any code in the main activity other than `setContentView`.

Comment: Oh, if the answer helped you out and you've solved your issue you should accept it (click the check mark next to it).  This lets everyone know your issue is resolved and gives some credit to the person that helped you.

Comment: and where should I put the tag of my fragments ? if they ain't in xml.

Comment: Ok so if I dont need to put any code I also don't need the tag... or do I ? When I will want to change content of one fragment, how should I do ? how can I retrieve my fragment ?

Comment: Tag?  You don't need a tag unless you want to use `findFragmentByTag`, and you don't need to as you know exactly where your fragments are since you are hardcoding them in.  Tags are a convenience, not a requirement.  :)

Comment: What do you mean by "change the content"?  Put a different fragment in?

Comment: Ok now I am a bit confused regarding what is in what and where it is coded. let's say I want configuration explained above (2 frag etc..). So i've got 2 customs layout coded in xml, and i want each one in a fragment. So in my fragment jave code I implement onCreateView which will return one my layout (i do same for both). In my main activty I set the content view with a xml layout file containing two frame layout , each one for one of my fragments (with android:name="myfrag.."). is that it ? because it display nothing :/

Comment: Updated  my answer.  To use android:name you have ot give it the full package name to your class.  `android:name="your.package.name.classname"`... not just `android:name="classname"`